# Check if product is new using observer

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have observer targeted on "catalog_product_save_after" event.

Need to check if current product is completelly new and not one of existing items.

How to do this?

Comment: You want to check the current product is existing in quote or not?

Comment: Not sure about quote, because haven't investigated mechanism of product creation. To be more concrete: need to find out if admin creates new product. For existing products my action shouldn't perform.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For detecting new entity you can use

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$product->isObjectNew();
```

*Source:*
`\Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Observer\ReportProductSaved`

Answer (score 4):

For me the `isObjectNew()` was available in `catalog_product_save_before`, but was not available in `catalog_product_save_after`.  I simply created my own `isNew` variable in the Observer and set it to true in `beforeSave` and checked it in the `afterSave` methods.

```
<?php
class Some_Module_Model_Observer{
protected $isNew = false;
public function beforeSave($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if($product->isObjectNew()){
        $this->isNew = true;
    }
}
public function afterSave($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if($this->isNew){
        /*Add Logic Here*/
    }
}
```

}